# How to do a total charges lookup?

Tags: excel

Let say I have a sheet with the following list of orders:

```
Order   Value
1234    $50
1234    $50
2345    $60
2345    $60
```

I need a separate sheet that will look up and calculate the total charges for each order like this:

```
Order Value
1234  $100
2345  $120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum range])`:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$5,A8,$B$2:$B$5)
```

[image]

Or if it's a lot of data, you can always use a Pivot Table.